# Importing a Form from another project

Tags: c#

I am trying to import a form from old project to my new project. In order to do so I go to solution explorer in the new project and right click the project name and Add –Existing Item and navigate the the target form file (in my case it is Form9). This all works OK
The problem now is when I try to load the imported form(Form9) I get this error

> The type or namespace name 'Form9' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

I am using this code to load Form9

```
Form9 frm9 = new Form9();
frm9.Owner = this;
frm9.ShowDialog();
```

Did I miss any step?

Comment: Did you add the namespace?

Comment: Where to add this  ?

Comment: Offtopic: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in the form's .cs file.  At the top of it, it has a namespace declaration that should correspond to the namespace of your project.  It probably still has the name of the old project. Change it to be the correct namespace (your new project).

Comment: "At the top of it, it has a namespace", I'd change this to "At the top of it, it should have a namespace declaration". The namespace can be removed